# Nonblocking simultaneous assignments to wires and registers in Verilog

Tags: verilog, nonblocking, assign

I am interested to write Verilog module which simultaneously will update several outputs
Something like following code, makes 3 operations at the same time (clk 10):

```
module mymodule (a,b,c,d,e);
input a;
input b;
output c;
output d;
output e;

wire b;
wire a;
wire c;
wire d;

reg e;

initial begin
c <=  #10  (a+b);
d <=  #10  a;
e  <= #10  b;
end

endmodule
```

Is that code legal?

Comment: What are you trying todo with `#10`, add delay to the continuous assignment?

Comment: @Morgan - I need ALL 3 assinment operations to c ,d and e be done at the same clock (clock 10)

Comment: You need the clock to be an input then and infer flip-flops.

Comment: NB: a+b would be a 2 bit result you are only keeping the LSB, This is the XOR operation `^`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How todo a one off assign of variables after 10 timeunits or clocks:

As a testbench level construct:

```
reg c,d,e;
initial begin
  #10;
  c = a+b;
  d = a;
  e = b;
end
```

For RTL (synthesis) first you need a testbench with a clock.
I would generate a clock like this in my testharness :

```
reg clk ; //Rising edge every 10 timesteps
initial begin
  clk = 0;
  #5; 
  forever begin
    #5 ;
    clk = ~clk;
  end
end
```

Build a counter which counts to 10 and once it reaches 10 Enables the flip-flop to load new values.

```
wire enable = (counter == 4'b10);
always @(posedge clk or negedge rst_n) begin
  if (~rst_n) begin
    c <= 1'b0;
    d <= 1'b0;
    e <= 1'b0;
  end
  else if (enable) begin
    c <=  (a+b);
    d <=   a;
    e <=   b;
    end
  end
endmodule
```

**Extra Verilog Tips**
Outputs are implicitly wires no need to redefine them.

Non-Blocking assignments `<=` are for use in an always `@(posedge clk)` when inferring flip-flops.

`reg`s or `logic` types can be assigned inside `always` or `initial` blocks. `wire`s are used with `assign` or for connectivity between ports.

Comment: The assinments should be timed to clk 10.

Comment: Thanks for update.But the outputs should be updated not just on on the same clock but on SPECIFIC clock (for example clk #10)

Comment: - OK.I got that it is a delay.Can you please tell me how using a clk input - make the assignment when clk is 10?

Comment: I want the module to perform the assignment operations only ONCE when the clock is exactly 10 timestamps

Comment: Is this for behavioural (testbench) or for synthesis?

Comment: Once it is synthesised and put on fpga/asic you will not have timesteps you need to start generating a clock.

Comment: I don`t totally understand your last comment - can you please direct me by code example how should it be if it is for  synthesis and how do I "start generating a clock"?

Comment: Time steps only exist in the simulator, your FPGA must receive a clock, this is available to be used as an input by your module. I have included a way of creating a testbench clock.